# В каждом из каталогов внутри abc создать файл 1.txt, содержание которого - уровень каталога относительно abc

Tags: linux, bash

```
find ~/abc -type d | awk '{t=$1 "/1.txt"; gsub("[^/]","",$1);print length($1)-3; print t;}' | xargs -n2
```

Необходимо значения из первого столбца (Уровень каталога относительно abc) вставить в соответствующие файлы из второго столбца (Адрес и название файла, файлы ещё не созданны)

Comment: Я тут мимокрокодил, можно полюбопытствовать: а зачем вам это?? Вы же заполнив этими файлами что-то потом дальше будете считать, верно? Есть обоснованное подозрение, что это [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987) и можно решить вашу исходную задачу не решая текущую промежуточную.

Comment: Это пункт задания лаб роботы (1 курс)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У утилиты [**find**(1)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=find) есть действие `-printf`, которым можно сформировать команду оболочки для вывода уровня каталога (`%d`) в файл-результат в том же каталоге. Выглядеть это будет так.

```
find ~/abc -type d -printf 'echo %d >%p/res.txt\n' | sh -
```

Предполагается, что в путях к папкам внутри `~/abc` нету необычных символов (таких как пробелы, кавычки, обратные слэши, точки с запятой, переносы строк и проч.), в этом случае команда отработает нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, вывод сделал в 1.txt
`find ~/abc -type d -printf 'echo %d >%p/"1.txt"\n' | sh -`